# php-cs-fixer got broken for linux users after fixing the issue 6 for windows users

Tags: atom-editor

I use Linux Ubuntu 16.04. I have well installed php-cs-fixer for atom 1.9.8.

```
$ php-cs-fixer
PHP CS Fixer version 1.11.6 by Fabien Potencier

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  fix          Fixes a directory or a file
  help         Displays help for a command
  list         Lists commands
  readme       Generates the README content, based on the fix command help
  self-update  Update php-cs-fixer.phar to the latest version.
  selfupdate   Update php-cs-fixer.phar to the latest version.
```

The problem comes with config of php-cs-fixer with atom. In fact, package requires:

- a PHP Executable path (which is by defaut `php`) (for linux user it must be empty which is not possible with actual version of the  package) (see isse [#6](https://github.com/pfefferle/atom-php-cs-fixer/issues/6) )
- a PHP-CS fixer Executable path (which is simply for linux user `php-cs-fixer` *(without the use of PHAR file)*)

Consequently, when I run php-cs-fixer from atom I get this error: **Could not open input file: php-cs-fixer**.

I can generate this error message with this console command:

```
php php-cs-fixer fix Class.php 
    Could not open input file: php-cs-fixer
```

So, can you make `PHP Executable path` optional (not compulsory) for that package of atom???

thanks,

---

### Update on this issue:

I managed to download `php-cs-fixer.phar` from https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer and I put it in the folder `~/.composer/` so that:

- a PHP Executable path is `php`
- a PHP-CS fixer Executable path is: `~/.composer/php-cs-composer.phar`

But now I am getting this error: **Could not open input file: ~/.composer/php-cs-fixer.phar**

So what's wrong??

For you information, running the console `php ~/.composer/php-cs-composer.phar Class.php` command is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is found on github:

- a PHP Executable path is `php`
- a PHP-CS fixer Executable path is: `/home/username/.composer/php-cs-composer.phar` and don't use the `~` in atom.